# FOSRestBundle Annotations for GET

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am currently developing an API and am using FOSRestBundle. I've gone wrong somewhere with the annotation side of my controller.

Please see my code below:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;

class DefaultController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\("/default/{string})
     * @param string $string
     */
    public function defaultAction($string)
    {}
}
```

I am trying to to pass a parameter to the default action and do something with it. However, the parameter I include in the URL isn't getting passed to the action. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the `Get` from your first annotation, it should be: `@Rest\Get("/default/{string}")`

Comment: That was it! Thanks!